# What should the container color of the top app bar be in Material 3?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-design, android-jetpack-compose-material3

When using the `TopAppBar` material component, there is no background color by default.

Should I set the container color of the app bar and the status bar to `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer` or is `secondaryContainer` better to let the `floatingActionButton` stand out?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TestAppBar(){
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(
                text = "Title",
//                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer
            )
        },
        actions = {

        },
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
//            scrolledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
            titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer
        ),
//        scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior()
    )
}
```

---

Since `rememberSystemUiController()` doesn't have a `.getStatusBarColor()` method, I found that the status bar color corresponds to `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary`. Should the status bar and app bar have the same color?